# Miracasting video plus sound on Android/Xiaomi/Miui: how to direct sound, too, to wireless display by code?

Tags: android, xiaomi, miui, miracast

Casting video plus sound programmatically to miracast from Xiaomi Redmi 5:

I CAN cast a YouTube video plus sound from the redmi to the miracasted wireless display, and the sound will be emitted from the wireless display speaker.

When I try to cast video plus sound by code using the Android MediaRouter including a video track including sound, the video appears on the wireless display but sound is emitted from the mobile phone.
What trick is needed to programmatically cast both, video and sound, together?